# Set Global Axis Options PGFPLOTS

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

for some reason setting global options using pgfplotsset while drawing a global legend using the tikz library matrix, does not work. The legend actually does not show at all, so something is wrong. I only need to the legend to be drawn for three entries.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,
            compat=1.9,
            }

\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
            
\pgfplotsset{xlabel style={xlabel=$x$, label style={font=\HUGE}}, 
            every axis plot/.style={line width=5.5pt},
            every axis post/.append style={xmin=-10, xmax=10}}

\begin{axis}[name=t1, height=5cm, width=10cm]
\addplot[color=red] table[x=time, y=d1]{distances1.dat};\label{plots:dissociated}
\addplot[color=blue] table[x=time, y=d2]{distances1.dat};\label{plots:bound}
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[name=t1a, at={($(t1.east)+(1cm,0cm)$)}, anchor=west, height=5cm, width=10cm]
\addplot[color=green] table[x=time, y=d3]{distances1.dat};\label{plots:angle}
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[name=t2, at={($(t1.south)+(0cm,0cm)$)}, anchor=north, height=5cm, width=10cm]
\addplot[color=red] table[x=time, y=d1]{distances2.dat};
\addplot[color=blue] table[x=time, y=d2]{distances2.dat};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[name=t2a, at={($(t2.east)+(1cm,0cm)$)}, anchor=west, height=5cm, width=10cm]
\addplot[color=green] table[x=time, y=d3]{distances2.dat};
\end{axis}


\begin{axis}[name=t3, at={($(t2.south)+(0cm,-1cm)$)}, anchor=north, height=5cm, width=10cm]
\addplot[color=red] table[x=time, y=d1]{distances3.dat};
\addplot[color=blue] table[x=time, y=d2]{distances3.dat};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[name=t3a, at={($(t3.east)+(1cm,0cm)$)}, anchor=west, height=5cm, width=10cm]
\addplot[color=green] table[x=time, y=d3]{distances3.dat};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[name=t4, at={($(t3.south)+(0cm,0cm)$)}, anchor=north, height=5cm, width=10cm]
\addplot[color=red] table[x=time, y=d1]{distances4.dat};
\addplot[color=blue] table[x=time, y=d2]{distances4.dat};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[name=t4a, at={($(t4.east)+(1cm,0cm)$)}, anchor=west, height=5cm, width=10cm]
\addplot[color=green] table[x=time, y=d3]{distances4.dat};
\end{axis}

\coordinate (bot) at (rel axis cs:1,0);

\matrix[
    matrix of nodes,
    anchor=south,
    draw,
    line width=1pt,
    inner sep=0.2em,
    draw
  ]at([yshift=-5ex]legendpos)
  {
    \ref{plots:dissociated}& Dissociated &[5pt]
    \ref{plots:bound}& Bound &[5pt]
    \ref{plots:angle} & Angle &[5pt]\\};`

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Does anyone know how to draw the legend properly, and also why the use of matrix effects the setting of global options using pgfplotsset?

Comment: You use ancient `pgfplots` package. Recent version is 1.18. BTW, your document example is not complete, missed is file `distances1.dat`.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX:SE!

Since you not provide file `distances1.dat` we can't test your document example (it also contain some errors, please check it again). However, this works:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.18,
    %
    height=5cm, width=10cm,
    xlabel=$x$, label style={font=\huge},
    every axis plot post/.append style={line width=5.5pt},
    xmin=-10,
    xmax=10
            }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=-9:9, samples=11]
    \addplot    {x};
    \addplot    {2*x};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If my `\pgfplotsset` works with your page, you need to test yourself (but I don't see any reason why will not).

Comment: Thanks, I have gotten that to work fine now for an array of plots (if I remove the node I was trying to draw to reference the different plot labels in a kind of self constructed legend). Although I would very much like to have one global legend for a series of plots. I can not do this using the default addlegend entry as the plots in each axis environment are not the same in each instance. I know I can save the plots I want in the legend using \label and the reference them using \ref as I tried above, but getting them in a box at the bottom the figure is a problem.

Comment: @Kyle, you can globally define legend style, however, they content should be determined inside `axis` environment. If you have new problems, please ask new question an in it provide compete document (MWE: Minimal Working Example) which reproduce your problem that people can copy  and compile it as it is. Your comment is no visible to people who may help you. BTW, if my answer solve your question, you may consider to accept it (by clicking on the check mark at the top left side of answer).